# How to disable scaling from 4K to FullHD on Panasonic TV?

Tags: firefox-os, pdf.js

First of all, sorry for my English :)

I'm developing an app for Panasonic 4K TV (50CX680E) using WebIDE(FF 42.0) on Windows 10. I'm connected to TV via Remote Runtime. My laptop screen resolution is 1920x1080.

When I run my app on TV it's running with 1920x1080 resolution and i can't reach 4K. First I was thinking that this is running on my laptop resolution by when i change it to lower the app on tv stays on FullHD. I need 4K because my app displays 10 pages of PDF via pdf.js and in FullHD PDFs are unreadable. Is there a solution to disable scaling?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "4K" ?

Comment: I mean 3840 × 2160. App is scaled to 1920x1080 by default.

Comment: How do you actually know that the resolution is scaled? You're taking measures from the elements using WebIDE ?

Comment: It is very simple. For example css 1px border is not a physically 1px on TV screen. Other way is to put 3840 × 2160 image to app, when i do that scrollbars appears and i can see 1/4 of the image. I can check it in console by tapping "window.innerWidth" or "window.innerHeight" and it gives me 1920 and 1080.